# How to replace a few Barricade subfloor panels

Tags: basement, subfloor

I have about 400 sq ft of 2'x2'x7/8" [Barricade Subfloor Air Plus](https://barricadesubfloor.com/about-air-plus/) in my basement. After some recent water damage, I had to tear out approx. 15 panels (60 sq ft). I tried to buy the same product but it seems they only make it in 3/4" now. How can I replace the missing panels without having to replace the entire subfloor with 3/4"?

Comment: Are they tongue and groove?  I'd say that you could just make up the 1/8" difference with some kind of material, but having to center a tongue or even expect it to fit in the existing groove, thats another thing.  What finished floor is going on top of it?

Comment: @JPhi1618   Good point about the tongue and groove not fitting in right.  If not that it would be simple.

Comment: They are tongue and groove. We are planning on putting LVT on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manufacturer responded with the following:

> The dimensions of our panels changed, over 5 years ago now. They were
> at one time manufactured using a 5/8” OSB, resulting in a 7/8” thick
> panel. Once the 5/8” OSB was no longer available to us by our
> suppliers, we switched to the “tried and true” 15/32” OSB used on our
> DRICORE R+ Insulated panels resulting in a ¾” thick panel. The 7/8”
> panels are no longer available.
>
> To install old and new together, simply lift the new thinner profile
> subfloor slightly to align the tongue and groove, then tap in to
> place. Place DRICORE shims on gaps between the subfloor and your
> concrete floor when those gaps are less than ¼”, including the point
> where the new thinner profile DRICORE meets up with the pre-existing
> product. There will be a small lip, which you can sand down where the
> seams meet. Note: this method will result in a slight slope.
>
> Alternatively, you can cut the tongues off the new thinner panel, butt
> them up tight against the old panels and anchor them into place using
> concrete screws. We recommend flat head 1-3/4 x ¼” Concrete screws (IE
> Tapcon) and a 4-1/2 x 3/16” Drill bit to bore the holes. Once the
> panel is in place, you can cover with a plywood (Which is required for
> your application regardless), thickness determined by panel height
> difference.
>
> Thank you for choosing DRICORE Products. Please do not hesitate to
> contact me should you require further assistance.

Comment: Nice! Congrats on actually contacting the manufacturer, and thanks for reporting back.